# How to change usergroup?

Tags: linux, permissions, opensuse, group

I've created a new user for FTP.

```
useradd -g www-data -d /srv/www/vhosts/project/ black
```

I made a mistake, I actually need the user to be in the group `www`.

How can I change the group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
sudo groupadd www # Add a new group, if not exists
usermod -a -G www black # Add the existing user black to www
usermod -g www black # Change the primary group of black to www
```

To confirm that it has been added:

```
groups black
```

From removing user from secondary group, in this case `www-data` group:

```
gpasswd -d black www-data
```